# Get $id from nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a post/comment system in Angularjs and Firebase, I can loop without problem to show all the post with ng-repeat and its comments as well. The problem start when I tried to get the $id from the second nested ng-repeat to be able to save the replies into the comment. Let's see the code I have:

```
<div class="posts" ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <div>{{post.text}}</div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Comment here..." ng-model="comment">
    <button ng-click="addComment(post, comment)"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="comments" ng-repeat="cmt in post.comments">
    <p>{{cmt.text}}</p>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="answer">
      <button ng-click="addAnswer(cmt, post)"></button>
    </div>
      <div ng-repeat="answer in cmt.answers">
      <p>{{answer.text}}</p>
      </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

app.js

```
$scope.addComment = function(post, comment){

    var ref = new Firebase("https://url.firebaseio.com/users/" + post.$id + "/comments");

    var comments = $firebaseArray(ref);

    comments.$add({

    text: comment

   });

}

$scope.addAnswer = function(cmt, post){

        var refanswers = new Firebase("https://url.firebaseio.com/users/" + post.$id + "/comments/" + cmt.$id + "/answers");

        var answers = $firebaseArray(refanswers);

        answers.$add({

        text: answer

       });

    }
```

To test, first I remove the code above inside addAnswer function and write two console.log to check if Im getting the values

console.log(post.$id);

console.log(cmt.$id);

I get only the post.$id but no the second one (undefined), am I missing something about nested ng-repeat?

**Edited: I changed the code to avoid the $scope conflict following the answers below but still does not work.**

Any advice is welcome, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`comment` being passed into `addAnswer()` is likely not the instance object of the ng-repeat as you are thinking, rather it could be clashing with the `ng-model='comment'` already defined above. You have a scope issue.

This may be fixed by changing `ng-repeat="comment in post.comments"` to `ng-repeat="cmnt in post.comments"`or whatever you want to name it, as long as it doesn't conflict with previously defined $scope objects.